# This expression will be resolved to Int in further releases. Please add explicit convention call

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin 1.5.20 I'm getting this warning: "This expression will be resolved to Int in further releases. Please add explicit convention call"
Pardon my French, but WTH does that mean?

Here is an example that gives the warning:

```
   assertThat(rr.maxRuntimeSeconds).isEqualTo(60*60*24*2)
```

The warning is caused by the isEqualTo which takes an Any

Comment: What's the expression?

Comment: @HenryTwist added an example. JetBrains said that it's a typo and should be "conversion" call, which makes more sense, but I'm still confused as to why

Comment: What's the type of `rr.maxRuntimeSeconds`?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a `Long`; and that the body of `isEqualTo` is converting its argument to a `Long` too, but won't do that in future versions without an explicit conversion.

Comment: @Noah I think you are right, I was focusing on the right side, not the left

Comment: @Noah that was it, feel free to answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Noah comment it's about auto conversion but won't do that in future versions without an explicit conversion.

This is OK:

```
assertThat(rr.maxRuntimeSeconds.toInt()).isEqualTo(60*60*24*2)
```